# Error trying to start Minecraft Forge by command

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am currently developing a custom Minecraft launcher and I want to start Minecraft forge by command line, but unfortunately I constantly get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Patcher expecting non-empty class data file for net.minecraft.entity.projectile.EntityThrowable, but received empty, your vanilla jar may be corrupt.
```

I already tried changing the 1.10.2.jar file with another but the issue persist; I also tried using a clean installation of minecraft and forge to check that both libraries and assets weren't corrupt.
Any suggestion?
Here my entire command: https://pastebin.com/7ekFNffH
I have structured the launcher folder like this:

```
LauncherFolder/
         |- Libs/
         |    |- "All the jar files used as libraries"
         |
         |- Assets/
         |    |- "the copy of Minecraft assets folder"
         |
         |- 1.10.2.jar
```

Ps: the vanilla version start without any issue

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, take a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and adequate your concerns to StackOverflow!

Comment: As [LexManos told you](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/60744-1102-custom-launcher-crash/#comment-283624), don't make custom launchers.

Comment: Anyway I solved it and now I have my custom launcher ;)

Comment: @TitoTigi how did you solve it?

Comment: @Limmy It's very simple. Install a forge instance on the minecraft launcher and start it. Using procexp64 you will see the command executed by Minecraft when starting the game. You should find the minecraft process under "javaw". Tell me if you find it. You can try my launcher here: http://spank.soulnetwork.it:1337/releases/stable

Comment: @TitoTigi thank you, it helped :)

Comment: You are welcome :)